# Smoother CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have been trying all the morning to make this more smoother:
http://codepen.io/alexrts/pen/jbNrXo

```
-webkit-animation: pulse 1.4s ease-out; 
-moz-animation: pulse 1.4s ease-out; 
animation: pulse 1.4s ease-out; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

As you can see, it looks a little bit robotic. 
Does anybody knows if there's a way to do it without javascript?

Best,
Alex

Comment: Because your keyframes are irregular and your easing isn't linear: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYPbbx

Answer (score 3):

You should make the easing linear

```css
html {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.live-cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.live-icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.live-text {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
  color: #007aff;
}

.live-arrow {
  background-image: url("http://s18.postimg.org/u8099c1c5/live_arrow.png");
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.live-pulse-min {
  border: 4px solid #007aff;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 11px;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.4s linear;
  -moz-animation: pulse 1.4s linear;
  animation: pulse 1.4s linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.live-pulse-max {
  border: 4px solid #007aff;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-animation: pulse2 1.4s linear;
  -moz-animation: pulse2 1.4s linear;
  animation: pulse2 1.4s linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "pulse2" {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="live-cta">
  <div class="live-icon">
    <div class="live-arrow"></div>
    <div class="live-pulse-min"></div>
    <div class="live-pulse-max"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="live-text">LIVE</dive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a linear easing by adding this line of css to your specified animations:

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

[I edited your code here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epOBgr)